# How to get Git Merged Date Revision Log history?

Tags: git, merge, git-log

Let say there are 3 branches: A, B, and C.

- A was merged 2 days ago.
- B was merged 3 days ago.
- C was merged 2 weeks ago.

I would like to get the information below from git history:

1. Git History dated 1 weeks ago

   So, it would only show A, and B.
2. The retrieved information should only contains:

   a. The revision log when it was merged.
     For example, revision 45edfe, with the auto comment by GIT like "Merge branch XXXX".

   b. Branch Name if possible.

   c. Merged Date

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git log` with the `--after` and `--merges` switches like this:

```
git log --after="2015-5-23" --merges
```

The current date as of writing this answer is 29 May, 2015.  The above command will get all merge commits which have happened in the last 7 days (*inclusive* of 2015-5-23).

A typical `git log` entry looks like this:

```
$ git log
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Hatjhie <hatjihie@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 29 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    Added new UI feature
```

You typically will run `git log` for a given branch, and the revision log and branch name are implicitly included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it would also get the commit which is not "merge" history.Is there a way to filter it by git command and not by commited comments?

Comment: Updated my answer to only get commits from the last week which are merge commits.

Answer (score 3):

This tool can help you to find when a branch was merged into another: https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged